# splat operator in groovy?

Tags: groovy, dsl

```
def foo(map, name) {
  println(map)
}

foo("bar", hi: "bye")
```

will print

```
[hi:bye]
```

Now I have a previous map that I wish to pass along to foo. In pseudo code, something like:

```
def otherMap = [hi: "world"]
foo("bar", hi: "bye", otherMap*)
```

So that it prints

```
[hi:world]
```

This doesn't work of course.

Also, trying to pass just the map mixes the order of arguments:

```
def otherMap = [hi: "world"]
foo("bar", otherMap)
```

will print

```
bar
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: How do you expect `foo("bar",otherMap)` to print something else than `bar`? You're printing the first parameter.

Comment: @Geo yeah I was wondering about the same (but I'm new to Groovy so don't know). Especially I'm puzzled in the OP how this:
 foo("bar", hi: "bye")
prints [hi: "bye"] rather than "bar" (but if you change to foo("bar", [hi: "bye"])) it works as expected. 
Could anyone enlighten please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for the spread-map operator.

```
def foo(map, name) {
  println(map)
}

foo("bar", hi: "bye")

def otherMap = [hi: "world"]
foo("bar", hi: "bye", *:otherMap)
foo("bar", *:otherMap, hi: "bye")
```

prints:

```
["hi":"bye"]
["hi":"world"]
["hi":"bye"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you exactly want to achieve, so here are several possibilities:

If you want to add the contents from the second map to the first map, the [leftShift](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#leftShift%28java.util.Map%29) operator is the way to go:

```
def foo(name, map) {
  println(map)
}

def otherMap = [hi: "world"]
foo("bar", [hi: "bye"] << otherMap)
```

If you want to access a parameter via its name use a Map:

```
def foo(Map args) {
  println args.map
}

def otherMap = [hi: "world"]
foo(name:"bar", first:[hi: "bye"], map:otherMap)
```

If you want to print all or only the last parameter use varargs:

```
def printLast(Object[] args) {
  println args[-1]
}

def printAll(Object[] args) {
  args.each { println it }
}

def printAllButName(name, Map[] maps) {
  maps.each { println it }
}

def otherMap = [hi: "world"]
printLast("bar", [hi: "bye"], otherMap)
printAll("bar", [hi: "bye"], otherMap)
printAllButName("bar", [hi: "bye"], otherMap)
```